# trying to run solr and getting an error?

Tags: openjdk, apache-solr

I am trying to run solr-9.4.0 and following exactly the instructions, running it through

```
bin/solr start -p 8984
```

but getting the error:

```
% cat server/logs/solr-8984-console.log
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: -XX:+UseLargePages not supported in this VM
CompileCommand: exclude com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/BoundedLocalCache.put bool exclude = true
WARNING: Using incubator modules: jdk.incubator.vector
WARNING: A command line option has enabled the Security Manager
WARNING: The Security Manager is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to register module: ${jetty.base}/modules/._gzip.mod
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Modules.registerModule(Modules.java:289)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Modules.registerAll(Modules.java:244)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.processCommandLine(Main.java:326)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:74)
Caused by: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
        at java.base/java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:279)
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:384)
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.lockedRead(StreamDecoder.java:215)
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:169)
        at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:188)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:160)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.implReadLine(BufferedReader.java:370)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:347)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:436)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Module.process(Module.java:367)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Module.<init>(Module.java:201)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Modules.registerModule(Modules.java:258)
        ... 3 more

Usage: java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar [options] [properties] [configs]
       java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar --help  # for more information
```

I am trying to decipher it, but can't really. I am running on macOS with Sonoma, openjdk 21.

I wish the errors were less cryptic so I can start with something.

I should mention I also tried:

```
#  bin/install_solr_service.sh
bin/install_solr_service.sh: line 70: ${distro_string,,}: bad substitution

ERROR: Unable to auto-detect your *NIX distribution!
You'll need to setup Solr as a service manually using the documentation provided in the Solr Reference Guide.
```

and there is no clue here how to proceed:

https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/deployment-guide/taking-solr-to-production.html

Comment: Use an earlier version of Java. The multiple warnings suggests that’s the solution and resolving the missing module